# code: "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR", errno: 1054, sqlState: "42S22", index: 0 MySQL/Angular/Sessions

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, angularjs, session

On my login page:

```
<div ng-include="'partials/navbar'"></div>

<form name="form"
      ng-submit="login(form)">

    <div>
        <input type="text"  
               placeholder="Email"
               name="username"
               ng-model="user.username"
               required>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="password"
               placeholder="Password"
               name="password"
               ng-model="user.password"
               required>      
    </div>

    <button type="submit"> Submit </button>

</form>
```

When submited, `login(form)` is executed here (in the login controller):

```
var app = angular.module('groundup');

app.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $location, Auth) {
  $scope.user = {};

  $scope.login = function(form) {
      Auth.login('my secret', {
          'username': $scope.user.username,
          'password': $scope.user.password
        },
        function(err) {
          if(err)
            console.log(err);
        }
      );
  };
});
```

Then, the call to `Auth.login` executes the below code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('groundup')
  .factory('Auth', function Auth($location, $rootScope, Session, User, $cookieStore) {
    $rootScope.currentUser = $cookieStore.get('user') || null;
    $cookieStore.remove('user');
    $rootScope.currentUserSignedIn;

    return {

      login: function(provider, user, callback) {
        var cb = callback || angular.noop;
        //console.log(user);
        Session.save({
          provider: provider,
          username: user.username,
          password: user.password,
          rememberMe: user.rememberMe
        }, function(user) {
          console.log(user);
          $rootScope.currentUser = user;
          $rootScope.currentUserSignedIn = true;
          return cb();
        }, function(err) {
          console.log(err);
          return cb(err.data);
        });
      },
```

The above code is where the error is thrown - it is having trouble with the POST request that is generated - and throws the error:

```
code: "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR", errno: 1054, sqlState: "42S22", index: 0
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with my `Session.save` method - which makes a POST call to `/auth/session` (The post call ends up being a `BAD REQUEST`). Here is my express route in case it helps, but I think the error has something to do with the names of the variables I am trying to store info in, and then pass to the passport login strategy:

```
app.post('/auth/session', session.login);
```

In another file (reference for `session.login`):

```
/**
 *  Login
 *  requires: {email, password}
 */
exports.login = function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err, user, info) {
    console.log(user);
    var error = err || info;
    if (error) { return res.json(400, error); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return res.send(err); }
      res.json(req.user.user_info);
    });
    //console.log(req.user);
  })(req, res, next);
}
```

So that is the whole flow - if anyone could help I would be greatly appreciated. It is storing the info as a session - so I don't think it has much to do with the names of the MySQL fields in the database, as I am not storing the sessions in a database (correct me if I'm wrong). I also have two questions - what are `user.rememberMe`, and `provider: provider` for? Thanks! I have tried taking those out of the object that gets saved in the session and it doesn't help - but I'm still not sure what they are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It had to do with a bad field name when I was checking to see if the user existed upon login. The error was in my local strategy for passport. Just another stupid one :).